# Why the expression is appearing as it is in AngularJS example?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, expression, javascript-framework

I've following code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
 <body>

   <p>Try to change the names.</p>

   <div ng-app="myApp">

     First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
     Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
     <br>


     Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

The output of above code in a browser is as below :

[image: Exact output in a browser]

```
Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}
```

My question is why the expressions are appearing as it is?

Comment: It appears you don't have a controller declared.

Comment: Buddy, where is your [ng-controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not register the angular module where the angualr bootstraps from this starting point.

```
<script>
angular.module("myApp",[])
</script>
```

And initialize with this module to the ng-app directive.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you've not define a angular app named `myApp`, you have to define the `ng-app` directive without any value.
`ng-app="myApp"` should be `ng-app`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <p>Try to change the names.</p>
  <div ng-app>
    First Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="firstName">
    <br>Last Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="lastName">
    <br>
    <br>Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

If you need to have a separate angular module, You can do like below

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <p>Try to change the names.</p>
  <div ng-app="myApp">
    First Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="firstName">
    <br>Last Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="lastName">
    <br>
    <br>Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What difference it makes if I avoid value of ng-app directive?

Comment: its not avoiding, you've not define a angular app named myApp, so you can't use that.

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined any controller in the `ejs` file.

add `ng-controller` along with `ng-app` and define that controller in your angular app.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
```

Define `Controller` in the `angular App` like this:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
    ...
});
```

Hope this helps you.